# Bootstrap, jsp, servlet, javascript

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have designed a web page using bootstrap and i have used jumbotron class for a login form and i need to make that jumbotron transparent so that background image will also be visible, Can anyone please suggest on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. Suppose you HTML is

```
<div class="cover">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>hello you</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, add some CSS to your code

```
.cover{
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/times-square-perspective.jpg');

}

.jumbotron{
  opacity:0.8;
}
```

You have to add a background image to the parent of **jumbotron** and reduce the opacity of the jumbotron class as shown above, to whatever extent you like.